# 'which' vs 'command -v' in Bash

Tags: bash

I've read in some bash FAQ a while ago (that I don't remember), that `which` should be avoided and `command -v` preferred.

Why is that so? What are the advantages, disadvantages of either one?

Comment: What? Why? `which` tells you where the executable of the program is located while `command -v` usually shows the _version_ of the executable

Comment: Here is the link: [Check if a program exists from a Bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script)

Comment: @anishsane - this question is "which is better", not "how do I..".  While the answer to that other question does explain the difference, the question itself is different.

Comment: Another builtin you can use in place of which is `type -p`. There is nothing wrong with `which` and it is provided on most distributions by default, but it isn't a shell builtin.

Comment: Oh, I meant "check the answer to that question". The question starts with _'ve read in some bash FAQ a while ago (that I don't remember)_ So my comment was here is the link. Sorry, I wasn't clear...

Comment: There are cases where `which` will return a different value from `command -v`, even for binaries.  `which` always scans the `$PATH` variable, but bash may hash the command, and not scan for it each time, so it will ignore if it is added/deleted anywhere in those locations.  Run `hash` to see which commands have been hashed, or e.g. `type ls` for a specific program

Answer (score 84):

Well...

`command` is likely built in to your shell, and with the `-v` option will tell you how your shell will invoke the command specified as its option.

`which` is an external binary, located at `/usr/bin/which` which steps through the `$PATH` environment variable and checks for the existence of a file.

A reason to select the former over the latter is that it avoids a dependency on something that is outside your shell.

The two commands do different things, and you should select the one that more closely matches your needs.  For example, if `command` is built in to your shell, `command -v command` will indicate this with its output (through the non-existence of path), but `which command` will try to point to a file on your path, regardless of how `command` would be interpreted by your shell.

Comment: `which` may also be built in to the shell, for example in `zsh`.  Both of them are a little difficult to depend on in a cross-platform manner.