# Bash - Print the full path of a file from $PATH

Tags: bash, shell, path, filepath

Say I have `~/scripts` in my `$PATH` and I have `script.sh` inside that path.

I can execute that script by typing `script.sh` directly in the terminal, but what if I want to print out the full path of that script without knowing the base path of the script (or added any function inside the script to print out its own path)? Are there any good ways to do this?

Comment: `which script.sh` should do it

Comment: ~ is the symbol of your home folder

Comment: In any POSIX compliant shell, avoid `which`, there are builtins that are well suited for that, like `type` , `hash` and `command`, unless `which` is a builtin also from the shell you're using then sure use it.

Comment: @jared_mamrot
Thank you, that did it! I don't know why it's borderline impossible to find the solution on google, I guess I wasn't using the right keywords

Comment: @Jetchisel Thank you, `command -v scriptname` seems to work well.

Comment: @Jetchisel can you tell me how to use `hash` to locate a file, do you refer to glibc ?

Comment: @MaxMuster  `help hash` ?

Comment: @Jetchisel strange, I do not have it on my computer, `sh: 0: Can't open help` it is probably in bash ...

Comment: @MaxMuster `man hash` to see the corresponding help page.

Comment: `bash -c 'help hash'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash, to locate a file (script) in the users path, you can use the `which` command: (https://ss64.com/bash/which.html), but as @Jetchisel says there are better alternatives for POSIX-compliant shells; see ['which' vs 'command -v' in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37056192/which-vs-command-v-in-bash)