# How to fully delete a NPM package from a mac?

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo

I have installed a tool called eas-cli from Expo.

I have ran all the commands I could think of, and even went to the root directory of npm and deleted the folder of it, but I still see results when I type eas --version in terminal. How can I fully delete this tool from my mac? is there a directory im not looking at ?

Comment: Try `which eas` in terminal. It should tell you where it is located.

Comment: you are a legend. I was growing grey hair. THANK YOU! If you have a buy me coffee or a tip link i would like to tip you.

Answer (score 3):

`npm uninstall -g eas` should uninstall the item from your path, but if it doesn't, then `which eas` will tell you where it is in your path, and `command -v eas` will tell you how your shell is invoking it. (Here's [the explanation of `command -v` vs. `which`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37056347/436641).)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't seem to get this package up to date or uninstalled, you may have used Yarn in the past.

Try `yarn global remove eas-cli` to completely remove the global Yarn package. If you then want to reinstall it, use `npm install -g eas-cli`. I have the global NPM command listed here because the eas-cli prompt to update always lists that command, so it might be doing your future self a favor to just use NPM to install globallys.